# Eclipse, error opening help pages

Tags: eclipse

I'm getting this error message:

```
could not open the browser because none are configured, check the web browser preference
eclipse Version: 3.3.2 (CDT)
Build id: M20080221-1800 - 
ubuntu 12.04 LTS
```

It appears when I go to the menu <kbd>Help</kbd> -> <kbd>Help Contents</kbd>

Also when accessing <kbd>Tutorials</kbd> on the `Welcome to Eclipse`-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to setup the web browser to show help pages in Eclipse

Select in the menu <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd>

[image: Menu Window -> Prefrences]

Then open <kbd>General</kbd> -> <kbd>Web Browser</kbd>. There select <kbd>Use external web browser</kbd> and select <kbd>Firefox</kbd>

[image: Preferences, Web Browser]

If the entry for Firefox is missing then hit the <kbd>New...</kbd> button. Enter `Firefox` as the name and `/usr/bin/firefox` as the Location (which is the default location for the Firefox web browser)

[image: Web Browser Name and Location Dialog. Firefox as example]

Comment: This is Eclispe for Windows. Right?

Comment: Changed it now to Linux screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, go to Menu Window --> Preferences.  Browse to General, then Web Browser.  Set up you browser there.  You will probably want to click on `use external web browser`, then give the path to your Firefox.  The search button should find your Firefox installation.

[image]